# build on top of Kickstart Neovim

Tags: terraform, neovim, lazy-initialization, neovim-plugin, nvim-lspconfig

## build on top of Kickstart Neovim

I m a noob using the git repo

https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim to configure Neovim

In the instructions inside the init.lua https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/init.lua#L263 it is mentioned to add the plugins in `lua/custom/plugins/*.lua

So I add the below contents in the file nvim/lua/custom/plugins/nvim-treesitter.lua

It doesnt return any error but it doest produce any results How to install the terraform lsp by adding a file under the lua/custom/plugins with minimal additions. or any lazyvim setup

I tried with below two steps

1. I have uncommented https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/init.lua#L269
2. Below are contents that I have added  in the file nvim/lua/custom/plugins/nvim-treesitter.lua

`

```
return { 
{ 
"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
 opts = { 
ensure_installed = { 
"hcl",
 "terraform", 
}, 
}, 
}, 
}
```

`